How to make VirtualBox use static IP?
I was using DHCP and everything worked fine.
Now since I needed to install Oracle DB I needed to change it to use static IP.
The VM is running Windows 10.
What would be the of using static IP with VirtualBox VM?
EDIT:
For testing i shut down VM and changed its network settings to be Host-Only Network with adding the adapter in the Host-Only Manager.
After restarting the VM, im getting the IP of 192.168.56.102, but trying to get out - ping google.com fails.
Trying to go and change the IP to mirror the one above in the Control Panel -> Network and Internet i see only one Ethernet adapter with No Internet.
Clicking on it and then clicking Edit, then choosing Manual, choosing IPv4 and entering respectfully 192.168.56.102, 24 and 255.255.255.0 i receive an error.
Entering 192.168.56.102, 24 and 192.168.56.1 is accepted, but still no internet...
What am I missing?

Please don’t include phrases like “TIA” in your question. This isn’t the first time you have been told this. I know users have mentioned this at meta.stackoverflow.com and on stackoverflow.com

“What would be the of using static IP with VirtualBox VM?” Is a very confusing question. Please clarify the question and make sure it’s grammatically correct. I don’t even know what your asking so I can’t correct your grammar.

Post screenshots (English) of your VMs networking configuration. Screenshots must either be English or an English Translation provided within the screenshot itself

@Ramhound, when I’m invited into the group of people I never knew, the very first word out of me is “Hi”.

@Ramhound, all I did was in the Control Panel/Device Manager, changed the IP settings and I lost access. Are you saying I should be using VM Network Configuration capability?

@Ramhound, moreover all of your guys are helping for free. The least I can do is to say “Thank you”.

You could but it will be immediately removed. Just avoid doing so.

IP configuration is done in the guest OS, isn't it?

@Bravo, Yes it is...

then the question is nothing to do with VirtualBox, you want to know how to set a static IP in windows 10?

@Bravo, I know how to do that in windows. Problem is - setting it for windows inside VM in VB.. As I just said - doing so I'm losing Internet access...


After restarting the VM, im getting the IP of 192.168.56.102, but trying to get out - ping google.com fails.

Stop at this point. If you're already getting an IP address via DHCP (with presumably the correct gateway address), and it doesn't work, then any manual IP configuration isn't going to make it better. A static configuration with the exact same parameters is going to behave the exact same way.
"Host-Only" adapters are somewhat misnamed; they can give Internet access, but they really rely on the host OS becoming a router (or a bridge) – almost exactly like 'tap' adapters in QEMU/KVM, for example. Without that additional configuration, packets from one adapter won't go to another by default.
For example, if your host OS is Windows, then you would need to enable IP routing/forwarding in Windows so that it would forward packets between the two interfaces (and generally also enable IP NAT/masquerading, e.g. through PowerShell's New-NetNat). Instructions for enabling IP routing for Windows and Linux are plenty elsewhere.
If that won't work, then switch back to VirtualBox built-in "NAT" – the guest can still have a static IP address with that mode too.

Clicking on it and then clicking Edit, then choosing Manual, choosing IPv4 and entering respectfully 192.168.56.102, 24 and 255.255.255.0 i receive an error.

The 3rd field is not the netmask – you already entered the netmask as 24 in the 2nd field, and the 3rd field is actually the gateway address. So this input is indeed incorrect, and (if I remember correctly) "192.168.56.1" is the correct gateway address – that being the host OS itself.

When you set a Guest to Host-Only network, you specifically tell that VM to have no external network access. You can still configure windows to work, see grawity's answer, but I usually go for a different approach, see below:
If you want this VM to reside in the network, like any other PC, set it to bridge.Then it can get an IP address from the DHCP server in the network and actually reach other network devices and pc's.
If just want this VM to have internet access and change the IP address, change the network type to NAT. This will place the VM in its own network, and you can use VirtualBox's DHCP server settings to change the IP address there to your liking. Note that in order for other pc's to reach your VM, you now have to open ports in the NAT manager.
If you want other pc's to reach your pc but not go through all the trouble, you can still use Bridge network mode, but now you need to know how the DHCP server in the network is configured, and either ask the admins to give your VM a static ip in the reservation, or change it to an IP address that is outside of the DHCP scope. This will be very tricky, so a NAT network (the above paragraph) is a much better solution if this is how you want to proceed.

I want to have  static IP on this VM and still have access to Web.  In the regular hardware I can achieve this by configuring the router to have static IP sent over.  Now I need to do that for VM…

The reason- I plan to install the DB on the machine and do the development work with frequently pushing/pulling the old code from/to GitHub. Connecting to the DB needs static IP and using GitHub needs Internet access.

Go the NAT route then. (3rd paragraph). Also, you can test if you can use ipaddress: 127.0.0.1 during the installation of the DB, and you may not even need to get a static ipaddress at all. Or do you want to connect to the DB in the VM from the Host? That part is not clear.

yes and not just from the host - from any machine on the network... it just will sometimes be easier and faster to test then waiting for the VM to show a single character for 5 min

Then the bridge route is the way to go, that places the VM inside the network like normal, and its ip address is visible to the entire network too. Need it static, get the network admins to make it static for you or alternatively, connect by hostname (computer name of the VM) instead, then it doesn't matter what the IP address is.

can you describe exactly what to do? I looked at the bridged VM setup, but i couldn't find any IP settings there...

Its very easy. You set it to bridge, and from that moment on, the VM is placed outside of the VirtualBox network system, and its part of the normal network. AKA, Ip management is done either through the DHCP server on the router, or in the Guest OS itself. Its basically the same as when your ISP modem is set to bridge mode. It forwards all incoming traffic to LAN port 1, no NAT translation at all. With Bridge mode in VirtualBox, all networking is passed through 1 to 1 as if the VM is an actual PC. Therefor, no config possible in VirtualBox possible either.

I just put the VM in the Bridge mode. And with the manual IP setting in Windows I don't have access. Should I set something in the router?

When setting it to bridge mode, the guest is essentially the same as another pc in the network, so treat it the same too. If you can't connect, check firewall settings, ping it, that kind of stuff.

so i tried to set Manual IP to 192.168.1.100 and keep it bridged, but then I don't have an Internet access. I guess it has something to do with the fact that Google Fiber is being stupid and is not letting people access to set up their internet access...

I guess I have only one option - have a bridged connection for the db and then switch to NAT for code retrieval..

Because with bridged I can't ping anything... or wait. What should I put as IPv4 gateway? My host IP or the router one?

When you set it to bridge, treat it like a different pc. So look at your own computer, what is your own IPv4 gateway? Your router right? Set it to that too.
